# Preact apparently ignoring preact.config.js file

Tags: preact

I'm developing an app using Preact. For context, here are my `package.json` scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider preact build",
    "serve": "sirv build --cors --single",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider preact watch",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

It used to work like a charm using `npm run dev`. Today I attempted `npm run build` for the first time and encountered

```
WARN Failed to load preact-cli config file, using default!
Function.prototype.apply was called on undefined, which is a undefined and not a function
```

There is a `preact.config.js` file in the right directory, and it was detected in watch mode, but apparently in build mode it is not.

Worse, after messing around and reinstalling all dependencies, it doesn't work in watch mode anymore. I don't get a warning about the presence or absence of the `preact.config.js` file, but Preact suddenly can't parse `otf` files anymore, even though a loader for that is configured in `preact.config.js`, which seems to indicate again that that file isn't detected (why watch mode suddenly can't find it is a mystery).

Here is my `preact.config.js`:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-var-requires */
const path = require('path');

export default function (config, env, helpers) {
    // Add a new rule for .otf fonts
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.otf$/,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        outputPath: 'fonts/',
        publicPath: '/fonts/',
      },
    });

    // Add an alias for 'phaser' to point to the non-ESM build
    config.resolve.alias['phaser'] = path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/phaser/dist/phaser.js');
    config.resolve.alias['@legion/shared'] = path.resolve(__dirname, '../shared/');


    let babelLoader = helpers.getLoadersByName(config, 'babel-loader')[0].rule;
    babelLoader.exclude = /node_modules\/phaser/;
}
```

My `preact-cli` version is `3.5.0`

Any hints as how I could resolve this?

Comment: What version of Preact-CLI are you running? Keep in mind that message is `Failed to load`, not failed to find. It's not that it can't detect it but that you're doing something during build that results in an error when trying to consume it.

Comment: @rschristian I edited the original post to add my preact-cli version which is 3.5.0 .
Any ideas what could be going wrong in the consumption of `preact.config.js` if the loading fails then, or how to diagnose it? And why it would work with `preact watch` and not `preact build`?

Comment: (Just to clarify, I am Preact-CLI's maintainer) If that's your full `preact.config.js`, not off the top of my head. Will look later. Generally speaking, that could happen if you're trying to access a loader (for example) that only exists in dev, yet your code assumes it exists in both and therefore throws in prod (as it doesn't try to check it exists before accessing internals). It shouldn't be an issue, but you should use es6 imports for `path` -- the cjs/esm interop we support is a tad fiddly at times and non-standard.

Comment: One option for diagnosing is a bunch of `console.log()` statements. See what line throws.